# Select Statement with INNER JOIN AND CASE

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get sql statement to link from one table to another and use a case (or if) if the user has accesslevel 1 then the statement should be `select * from campaigns`, whereas if ur not accesslevel 1 u should get the select statement as :

```
select * from campaigns WHERE campaign_Creator = ${user_ID}

SELECT * FROM campaigns 
INNER JOIN users ON campaigns.CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = users.USER_ID 
  CASE WHEN  users.USER_ACCESSLEVEL = 1 
  THEN SELECT * FROM campaigns 
  ELSE select * from campaigns WHERE CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = ${user_ID};
```

How would I go around creating such a statement? I've been trying to look it up but i just get more confused as to how to go around with this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Can't be done that way. A select has a constant number of returned columns, independent of table data. Do join, use where (or on) to restrict returned rows.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM campaigns 
INNER JOIN users ON campaigns.CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = users.USER_ID 
WHERE users.USER_ACCESSLEVEL = 1 
   OR CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = ${user_ID};
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution of our friend and complementing follow my suggestion.

```
SELECT *
    FROM campaigns
    INNER JOIN users ON campaigns.CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = users.USER_ID
    AND (users.USER_ACCESSLEVEL = 1 OR (users.USER_ACCESSLEVEL != 1
                                        AND CAMPAIGN_CREATOR = ${user_ID}))
```